# Xcode 4.2: xcdatamodel is marked as copied

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I recently upgraded Xcode to start ios5 development, but for some reason I encounter a very strange 
error with xcodes integrated version control. When I add a new model version and try to commit the changes to our repository I just get the following error:

> svn: Commit failed (details follow):
>   svn: Entry for '/Users/r2d2/Documents/workz/ios/blub iPhone 1.1/blub.xcdatamodeld/blub 3.xcdatamodel/elements' is marked as 'copied' but is not itself scheduled
>   for addition.  Perhaps you're committing a target that is
>   inside an unversioned (or not-yet-versioned) directory?

I could reproduce the bug on all our machines with Xcode 4.2 here.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I have the same issue

Comment: nope and it appears that of all the different subversion clients i have only subclipse was able to commit the changes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a mere formality, but here again is the answer for those who didnt find it yet:
use the subclipse for the eclipse IDE to do source control via subversion... any other client
i tried couldn't commit the changes....

Comment: ... that i need to use eclipse for commiting a renamed xCode project says quite something ..., thanks a lot - this tip made my day.

Answer (score 4):

I get this from Xcode all the time, but a simple commit from the command line always gets around it:

```
cd myProjectDirectory
svn commit -m 'My commit message.'
```

Seems to be a problem with Xcode's SVN support.

Comment: This should be marked as an answer to this question. Worked for me.